# How to install I/O parallel for netCDF4 on Linux?

Tags: parallel-processing, hdf5, netcdf4

I am attempting to install I/O parallel for netCDF4. The script I'm running is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

module purge
module load gcc/5.3.1
module load mpich/3.2

# zlib
cd /storage/home/htn5098/
mkdir -p local_lib/R40
cd local_lib/R40  
wget ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-4/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
tar -xf zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz && cd zlib-1.2.8
./configure --prefix=../zlib
make install
cd ../zlib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD/lib
cd ..
rm zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
rm zlib-1.2.8 -rf

# HDF5
wget ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netcdf-4/hdf5-1.8.13.tar.gz
tar -xf hdf5-1.8.13.tar.gz && cd hdf5-1.8.13
prefix="/storage/work/htn5098/local_lib/R40/hdf5"
export HDF5_DIR=$prefix
./configure --enable-shared --enable-hl --enable-parallel --prefix=$HDF5_DIR CFLAGS=-fPIC # important for parallel processing 
#./configure --enable-shared --enable-hl --prefix=$HDF5_DIR
make -j4
make install
cd $HDF5_DIR
export CPPFLAGS=-I$HDF5_DIR/include 
export LDFLAGS=-L$HDF5_DIR/lib 
cd ..
rm hdf5-1.8.13.tar.gz
rm hdf5-1.8.13 -rf

# NETCDF4
wget http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netcdf-c-4.7.3.tar.gz
tar -xf netcdf-c-4.7.3.tar.gz && cd netcdf-c-4.7.3
prefix="/storage/work/htn5098/local_lib/R40/netcdf"
export NETCDF4_DIR=$prefix 
./configure --enable-netcdf-4 -with-gnu-ld --enable-logging --enable-shared --enable-dap --enable-parallel-tests --prefix=$NETCDF4_DIR 
make -j4
make install
cd $prefix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/storage/work/htn5098/local_lib/R40/netcdf/lib/pkgconfig
cd ..
rm netcdf-c-4.7.3.tar.gz
rm netcdf-c-4.7.3 -rf

# R ncdf4 package
module load r
cd ~/work/local_lib/R40
wget http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/ncdf4_1.13.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL ncdf4_1.13.tar.gz --library=.
rm ncdf4_1.13.tar.gz
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
checking hdf5.h presence... no
checking for hdf5.h... no
configure: error: Compiling a test with HDF5 failed.  Either hdf5.h cannot be found, or config.log should be checked for other reason.
```

I think it might be the case of HDF5 library path is not shared with the netCDF4. Could you let me know how to compile HDF5 for to enable parallel for netCDF4?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I typically use on my Ubuntu server. It recently worked on a OpenSuse machine as well, with minimal modifications.

Note that there are multiple manual insertions of the installation dir `/opt/software` as arguments in `LDFLAGS` etc. You will also need to adapt those to your specific case.

```
# export installation directorie
export INSDIR=/opt/software

1) SZIP v2.1.1 - https://support.hdfgroup.org/doc_resource/SZIP

./configure --prefix=${INSDIR} \
    CC=gcc \
    CFLAGS="-march=native -g -O2 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wsign-compare -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -O -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions"

make && sudo make install && make all check

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2) HDF5 v1.12.0 - https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/source-code

# parallel version
./configure --prefix=${INSDIR} --disable-dependency-tracking \
    --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-silent-rules \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-pthread --enable-hl --enable-shared \
    --enable-build-mode=production --with-zlib \
    --enable-parallel --with-szlib=${INSDIR} \
    --disable-threadsafe --disable-fortran --disable-cxx \
    CC=/usr/bin/mpicc CXX=/usr/bin/mpicxx FC=/usr/bin/mpifort \
    "CFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security" \
    "FCFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong" \
    "CXXFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security"

make && sudo make install && sudo make check-install

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3) NetCDF C v4.7.4 - https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/index.jsp

# parallel version
./configure -prefix=${INSDIR} --enable-shared --enable-parallel-tests \
    CC=/usr/bin/mpicc CXX=/usr/bin/mpicxx \
    "CFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" \
    "CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/software/include" \
    "LDFLAGS=-L/opt/software/lib" \
    "LIBS=-lz -ldl -lm -lcurl -lpthread -L/opt/software/lib -lsz -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5"

make && sudo make install && sudo make check

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4) NetCDF Fortran v4.5.3 - https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/index.jsp

# parallel version
./configure --prefix=${INSDIR} --enable-parallel-tests \
    CC=/usr/bin/mpicc FC=/usr/bin/mpifort F77=/usr/bin/mpifort \
    "CFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" \
    "FCFLAGS=-march=native -g -O2 " \
    "CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/software/include" \
    "LDFLAGS=-L/opt/software/lib" \
    "LIBS=-L/opt/software/lib -lnetcdf -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now"

make && sudo make install && sudo make check
```

Also, note that the key step to enabling parallel features in this case is not using `make -j4`, but rather manually informing that you want to use the MPI compiler to build the libraries. This means that you **must** explicitly define the `CC`, `CXX`, `FC` etc flags as the MPI versions (mpicc, mpicxx, mpifort etc).

This should work, but keep an eye on the output of `make check` to see what is actually going on with the built libraries.

Comment: Do I need to call for all the CC, CXX and FC?

Comment: @Hainguyen not all of them. Netcdf-C for example, is a pure C program, and thus you don't need to call FC (which stands for Fortran Compiler). I think that you can get what is required by typing './configure --help'. Be aware that you have to compile netcdf with the very same compiler you used to compile hdf5, otherwise you'll get all sort of compilation issues. The safest approach to get parallel IO is to specify FC, CC etc for all the libraries.

Comment: I followed your steps. It asked for zlib. I installed zlib, but now I have an error: `checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in /storage/home/htn5098/local_lib/R40/netcdf-c-4.7.4':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'. Can you let me know why? I used `CC=mpicc` for both hdf5 and netcdf4